# how to set the alpha channel in canvas while grayscaling

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, grayscale

I am using HTML `canvas` to grayscale an image and I don't want to just average it. So I use this function

```
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var data= imageData.data
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      var grayscale = (data[i]*0.2126 + data[i +1]*0.7152 + data[i +2])*0.0722;
      data[i]     = grayscale; // red
      data[i + 1] = grayscale; // green
      data[i + 2] = grayscale; // blue
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

The problem is however, if the picture has the white background it will be turned into black. So tried `data[i + 3] = 255;` for the alpha channel but that turned the whole canvas into black.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
var grayscale = (data[i]*0.2126 + data[i +1]*0.7152 + data[i +2])*0.0722;
```

Note that the last constant multiplies the *entire* expresion to the left of it, whereas it should only multiply `data[i+2]`:

```
var grayscale = data[i]*0.2126 + data[i + 1]*0.7152 + data[i + 2]*0.0722;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NikolaDimitroff/vLmcseaq/)

Comment: FML, I am a noob! Thanks! So I was wondering if there is a way of separating only one channel in canvas. Similar to the IMagick `convert myfile.jpg -channel B -separate myfileR.jpg`

Comment: Well, use the same code as above, just set the channels you don't need to 0.

Comment: ok that works, but now if when I grayscale it again it turns the white space into black

Comment: how do I set the channels to 0 and maintain the white background as white at the same time?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you need to show only the blue channel for example, then you need to set the red and green channels to zero - `data[i]  = data[i + 1] = 0`. Unless there's no blue in that pixel, you'll never get a completely black color.

Comment: and I did that, however, it turns the white background picture into grey

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner That's impossible - if you filtered the blue channel out of a white picture you'll get an entirely blue picture. Please post your code in a jsfiddle or better - open another question.